# Are there any difference between the Power Functions 88003 and 99499 L motors?

Tags: power-functions, motor, electronics

I am planning to attempt a couple of RC MOCs and was looking up the power functions L motor on BL and found that there are actually 2 types of the L motor, namely the "88003 Power Functions L Motor" and the "99499 Power Functions 9V L Motor". From the somewhat limited information I could google, it seems like the 88003 can run on variable voltage (while I can't find the info on the 9V 99499 motor), it also seem like even their weights are different?

Can someone advice, or point me towards where I can find more information on these?

Answer (score 5):

According to bricklink, 88003 is the **set** containing exactly one **part**, namely the 99499 motor.
You can buy the motor as a set in LEGO shops or online, it's packaged in a plastic bag, which probably accounts for the 3 gram weight difference between the items.

To my knowledge there are no different versions of the Power Functions L motor.

Here is the list of the sets the motor appears in, note that 88003 is listed as well:
https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=99499c01&in=S

Comment: Hi Michael, that's great many thanks. Just got a little thrown off because the seller I was planning to purchase the motors from had both types at different prices(99499 being 10% more than the 88003). This was also made worse by the additional information/photo on BL that is different for both parts. when bricklink uses a different photo for both parts.

Comment: To me it seems that the picture for the set (88003) is the same as the picture LEGO S@H uses on its site to sell the set, while the picture for the part (99499) is a home-made picture taken by the bricklinker who added the entry... I have no idea why the BL seller would sell the single motor at a greater price than a packaged motor, I would expect it to be the other way around as a packaged motor is guaranteed 'new'...